# Disable audit object on oracle 11

Tags: oracle, auditing

How can I disable audit objects on Oracle 11? I have tried

```
NOAUDIT ALL; 
NOAUDIT NETWORK; 
NOAUDIT SESSION; 
NOAUDIT ALL ON DEFAULT; 
NOAUDIT SELECT INSERT UPDATE DELETE EXECUTE PROCEDURE; 
NOAUDIT PRIVILEGES;
```

But audit still generate, grows fast and, of course, my db becomes full.

When I query sys.aud, audit objects like insert, delete, update are being logged to sys.aud.

If someone has solution to this problem, please help me.

Comment: It would be better to ask this question on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: I already ask , but no answer on db forum ☺

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `init.ora` file so with the parameter `AUDIT_TRAIL=NO`.

Comment: That's my problem, I don't want to restart instance. Already read from oracle doc to use noaudit but it seems not working..

Comment: Yes this is production, i can't restart my server, until now sys.aud always full, and i'm getting tired to truncate sys.aud every 6 hour, any idea on this ?

Comment: Yes solve your system tablespace/disk size issue. Disabling auditing on a prod DB is a bad idea.

Comment: But how to restore default audit ?, before I execute audit all, everything is normal. I can audit user activity without sys.aud being full .. Is it any possible rollback solution ?

Comment: You cannot rollback audit settings. You made a change to a production environment without testing it so you made your bed now sleep in it. Above is how you disable all auditing and I recommend you consult someone before you make your next change.

Answer (score 0):

NOAUDIT works but for not current sessions. next sessions will not add audit data to sys.aud$

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is some kind of bug. I tried noaudit all. and restart the database. And reconfigured user audit. Then noaudit the user. It was worked for. Try:

```
no audit all
```

Then restart the database. Maybe help

Answer (score -1):

Use the query below to check the the privileges that are active and the to disable them, if that will help..

```
select username, owner, action_name, priv_used
from dba_audit_object;
```